# Can I convert a Vuejs project to Vue-Native?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a finished Vuejs project and  i want to make it as a native app, i want to know if i have to rewrite the whole application with Vue-Native components or is there  a way to convert my project to  a Vue-Native project.

Comment: Depends on your design - by default you have to use native components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No vue-native has different XML tags, Its very similar but would have to be rewritten

Comment: is it only the components that have to be rewritten? can i still use other dependencies?

Comment: from my understanding its just the components and you should be able to use npm modules if that is what you mean.